# Is there a list of stackoverflow.com locale variants?

Tags: support, localization

Our site allows users to add their Stack Overflow profiles to their user profile:

https://developer.mozilla.org/profiles/jwhitlock

We currently validate the URL with a Python RegEx:

`r'^https?://stackoverflow\.com/users/'`

A user asked to link to their profile on es.stackoverflow.com:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1306087

It's easy enough to allow this variant, but I'm wondering what other variants there are, and if there is a reference we can use to refresh the pattern in the future.  Is [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/117167/300203) as good as it gets?

Comment: Technically they are not just locale variants, they are full sites with their own community and rules. The list you have found is complete as of today.

Comment: Why not anything under stackoverflow.com domain?

Comment: I don't consider meta.stackoverflow.com profiles to be a strong indication of a person's value to my site's community. I'd rather they use their stackoverflow.com profile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from the regular site (https://stackoverflow.com/), we have four others:

Portuguese: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/
Spanish: https://es.stackoverflow.com/
Russian: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/
Japanese: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/

The best way to see this is to search for `stackoverflow` in the "Find a Stack Exchange community" bar, in the drop down.

There are no plans to launch more localized sites at this time.

---

So far, each localization uses a two letter prefix. Your regex could be:

```
r'^https?://(..\.)?stackoverflow\.com/users/'
```

If you let the prefix be any length, you risk getting meta profiles. (And localized meta profiles.)

Comment: There has been a statement by either Tim Post or Robert Cartino that until further notice no new localized sites will launch.